# Arduino - Simon Says programming issue

Tags: c++, loops, arduino

I tried to build a simple sketch for Simon Says game on my Arduino Uno.

I'm doing it right now on the breadboard, the plan is to make it portable with Attiny and shift-register, but that's only after I get the main code working properly.

In the loop, there's a `for` to create random values, and to decide which button to turn on. After that, according to my code, it's supposed to listen for the buttons input.

But, for some reason, it's stuck on the part that creates the random values. Starting at `}else if(reading == false){`

And here's what I get in the Serial window:
**Notice that I did not put any input to the arduino/serial during this run.

```
~~~Simon Says~~~
Here's the sequence!
Run: ID 0 LED 1
Run: ID 1 LED 1
Run: ID 2 LED 2
Run: ID 3 LED 2
I'm listening.
Here's the sequence!
Run: ID 0 LED 1
Run: ID 1 LED 2
Run: ID 2 LED 0
Run: ID 3 LED 2
I'm listening.
Here's the sequence!
Run: ID 0 LED 2
Run: ID 1 LED 1
Run: ID 2 LED 0
Run: ID 3 LED 2
I'm listening.
Here's the sequence!
Run: ID 0 LED 0
Run: ID 1 LED 2
Run: ID 2 LED 0
Run: ID 3 LED 3
```

> ```
> boolean reading = false;
> void loop()
> {
>   if(reading == true)
>   {
>     tell = deBounce(tell);
>     if(tell == 4)
>     {
>       int won;
>       for(int i; i<4; i++)
>       {
>         if( pressButtons[i] == buttons[i])won++;
>       }
>       if(won == 4){
>         ntln("Won");
>         for(int i; i<2; i++)
>         {
>           for(int k; k<4; k++)digitalWrite(led[i],HIGH);
>           delay(delaySwitch);
>           for(int k; k<4; k++)digitalWrite(led[i],LOW);
>         }
>         reading = false;
>       }else{
>         nt("Lost mistakes: ");
>         ntln(4-won);
>         digitalWrite(buz, HIGH);
>         delay(delaySwitch);
>         digitalWrite(buz, LOW);
>         reading = false;
>       }
>     }
>   }else if(reading == false){
>      ntln("Here's the sequence!");
>     for(int i; i<4; i++)
>     {
>       //if(mode > 0) buttons[i] = 
>       buttons[i] = random(0,3);
>       setLeds(buttons[i], true);
>       nt("Run: ID "); nt(i); nt(" LED "); ntln(buttons[i]);
>     }
>     for(int i; i<4; i++)digitalWrite(led[i],HIGH);
>     delay(delaySwitch);
>     for(int i; i<4; i++)digitalWrite(led[i],LOW);
>     ntln("I'm listening.");
>     reading = true;
>   }
>   delay(50);
> }
> ```

I pastled the whole loop section and the decleration of reading, other than these lines there's not any other use of that variable.

At the end of the -else- I declared reading to true,
but the arduino keeps going to that same -else-.. that's the problem basicly.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Post the code here, do not host it on some third party site.

Comment: On the comment section?

Comment: No, please edit your post to include your code. Indent the code by 4 spaces and it will show up as code in your post.

Comment: Oh I just noticed now it was a hebrew site, here you go a diffrent site. I don't want to post it here since it'll flood the page :)

Comment: @user2054911 Please add your code to this question; instead of adding *all* your code (if you think it's too much), please create [an MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Please do not include a link to download your code.

Comment: Added more info about the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing that created the bug was that I expected a x==0 in my for loop,
but I didn't set a value to x variable in the for loop.

I wanted the loop and X values to be 0,1,2,3 for my programming purposes.
Missing that 0 made all the difference.

Before: [X values would be: 1,2,3]

```
for(int x; x<4; x++)
```

After: [X values 0,1,2,3]

```
for(int x=0; x<4; x++)
```

That's what, ultimately made the bug.

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int i; i<2; i++)
{
    for(int i; i<4; i++)digitalWrite(led[i],HIGH);
    delay(delaySwitch);
    for(int i; i<4; i++)digitalWrite(led[i],LOW);
}
```

You have a problem in the section above. Looks like you're trying to declare the variable "i" within the scope of the loop where it's already declared. Try doing this:

```
for(int i; i<2; i++)
{
    for(int x; x<4; x++)digitalWrite(led[x],HIGH);
    delay(delaySwitch);
    for(int z; z<4; z++)digitalWrite(led[z],LOW);
}
```

Comment: That's absolutely right, I'll fix that,Thanks.
However, it's not what made the problem,
Notice the log of my Serial.
It seemingly "stuck" on the -}else if(reading == false){- section.

Comment: ok in that case try changing **this**:                            `for(int i; i<4; i++)digitalWrite(led[i],HIGH);`
`for(int i; i<4; i++)digitalWrite(led[i],LOW);`       **to:**  `for(int i; i<4; i++){ digitalWrite(led[i],HIGH); }`  `for(int i; i<4; i++){ digitalWrite(led[i],LOW); }`